# Unable to delete class from production

Tags: deployment, eclipse, delete, force.com-ide

For some reason I'm not able to delete specific class from production.

Earlier I comment all the code and it was deployed ok from Dev--> QA, and then from Dev --> Prod.
Now I want to delete this class using eclipse. I was able to do it from my QA sandbox, but not in production.

When trying I can see the deployment progress and see that it end succedeed (all green) + see the relevant class in archive folder (as eclipse ofer to save it for backup), but still after deployment the class remain in production.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm doing the exact same steps as I did when delete it from QA sandbox.

**Update 23-7-2017**

When trying with ant I got error message: 
**This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com.  Remove the usage and try again.
 : Scheduled Jobs - 08e2400000232Sb**

However scheduled job log is saved for 7 days and this class wasn't scheduled for long time. + When I query the cronTrigger in the org I see only 4 jobs, and the Id above is not part of them.

Should I need SF support to delete the mention id record?

Note, that I checked the flag :
"Allow deployments of components when corresponding Apex jobs are pending or in progress. Caution: Enabling this option may cause Apex jobs to fail."

[image]

Comment: try deleting with ant migration tool

Comment: hi. After trying with ant I got error message (updated in the message)